# How to use external services in Netty?

Tags: netty

I just started the implementation of a TCP server using Netty and two external services: MongoDB and Redis.
Since this is my first experience with Netty, I need some advice.

My doubt is, should I share a unique class instance for the external services between the incoming clients?

For example: 
Regarding Redis, I usually use a JedisPool class shared between the threads.

```java
 // Example
 // main class
public class Demo{
  public void demoClass(){
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool();
    for(int i = 0; i < 999; i ++){
       DemoThread thread = new DemoThread(jedisPool, i);
       thread.run();
    }
  }
}

// thread class
public class DemoThread{
  private JedisPool jedisPool;
  private int i;
  public DemoThread(JedisPool jedis, int i){
      this.jedisPool = jedis;
      this.i = i;
   }

   public void run(){
       Jedis redisClient = jedisPool.getResource();
       //...
   }
}
```

Following almost the same example, regarding MongoDB, I usually use a MongoDatabase class which it is shared between the threads.

```java
 // Example
 // main class
public class Demo{
  public void demoClass(){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("example");
    for(int i = 0; i < 999; i ++){
       DemoThread thread = new DemoThread(mongoDatabase, i);
       thread.run();
    }
  }
}

// thread class
public class DemoThread{
  private MongoDatabase mongoDatabase;
  private int i;
  public DemoThread(MongoDatabase mongoDatabase, int i){
      this.mongoDatabase = mongoDatabase;
      this.i = i;
   }

   public void run(){
       MongoCollection collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("example");
       //...
   }
}
```

Is it correct to do the same in Netty? Or, at every new client connected at the server, I must create new connections to the services?

If it is correct, then when and where should I instantiate the classes?
If not, then I must create a new connection for each client?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any class globally by creating its instance and injecting it to the ChannelHandler.